# nginx.conf with bitnami nginx debian as base image for docker

Tags: docker, nginx, bitnami

I am trying to dockerize my angular app. When I go to the web page, everything works fine until I refresh the page (F5). When I used nginx:1.17.1-alpine as the base image, I fixed the problem by using the following nginx.conf file instead of the nginx.conf default file:

```
server {
listen       4200;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}}
```

My dockerfile looked like that:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY /dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200
```

However now I need to use bitnami/nginx:1.21.6-debian-10-r88 as my base image.
When I try to build the container, I get the following error:

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
#15 0.399 rm: cannot remove '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf': No such 
file or directory
```

Anyone can help me figure out how to build the container properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nginx config is located in `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf`

As described in the [Readme](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/nginx) at `Step 1` you can copy your server-block config to

`/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I copied my custom nginx.conf to this directory and now it works.